# Getting a null pointer exception on a RecyclerView layout manager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, realm

Hi guys I have the following error I cannot seem to resolve.

I have

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference

The code I have is slightly different than from regular examples since I am doing this in a Fragment rather than in a Activity.

This is my code.
I have an xml for the whole Fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="mtr.MainActivityFragmentTwo">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/grades"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Then I have a content_fragment which holds the RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/realm_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Then my code in my Fragments looks as follows

```
public class MainActivityFragmentTwo extends Fragment {

    private Realm realm;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public MainActivityFragmentTwo() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity_fragment_two, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        realm.init(getActivity());
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.realm_recycler_view);
        setupRecyclerView();

    }

    public void setupRecyclerView() {
            Log.d("Found grades", "not showing grades tho");
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new gradeRealmAdapter(this, realm.where(Grade.class).findAllAsync()));
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }
}
```

the Adapter I created is

```
public class gradeRealmAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Grade, gradeRealmAdapter.GradeViewHolder> {

    private final MainActivityFragmentTwo activity;

    public gradeRealmAdapter (MainActivityFragmentTwo activity, RealmResults<Grade> realmResults) {
        super(activity.getActivity(), realmResults, true);
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public GradeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new GradeViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.gradeitem, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(GradeViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Grade grade = getData().get(position);
        holder.title.setText(grade.toString());
    }

    class GradeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnLongClickListener {

        public TextView title;
        public Grade grade;

        public GradeViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.grade_text_view);
            view.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        }

        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            activity.deleteItem(grade);
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

The error comes from the Fragment class on the following line

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));
```

I can't seem to resolve this.
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure recyclerView is not null? or even exists in the XML layout? Why not initialize your `RecyclerView` in `onCreateView` ? Are you sure your `onCreate()` is even being invoked/called/ran?

Comment: Try replacing this.getContext()) with getActivity()

Comment: .... Why are you trying to get the view from the activity?

Answer (score 2):

> I have an content_fragment which holds the recyclerview

Then you need to `findViewById` on **that** layout, not the Activity's.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity_fragment_two, container, false);

    // Don't use getActivity().findViewById
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.realm_recycler_view);

    setupRecyclerView();
    return rootView;
}
```

Then, you also have the `realm` initialization backwards.

```
realm.init(getActivity()); // This throws an exception as well
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); // It is initialized afterwards
```

So, fix that too within `onAttach`, where you are guaranteed to have some `Context`

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); 
    realm.init(context); 
}
```

Comment: I have changed it to this way but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Then `fragment_main_activity_fragment_two.xml` does not contain `@+id/realm_recycler_view`. That is the basic reason you get the NullPointer

Comment: but the content_main_fragment_two does contain that ID or should they both have it?

Comment: You can only inflate one layout in the Fragment, so I am not sure what you mean by both.

Comment: `content_main_fragment_two.xml` is not being loaded by the Fragment, `fragment_main_activity_fragment_two` is. If there is no RecyclerView element in `fragment_main_activity_fragment_two.xml` to find, then that causes a NullPointer. That is the documented feature of `findViewById`

Comment: The problem was that content_main_fragment_two.xml was not loaded indeed. I have placed the recyclerview part of content_main_fragment_two.xml in fragment_main_activity_fragment_two.xml and now its working but this is a very nasty solution. Is there a better solution? like to load the content fragment?

Comment: Use the correct layout that contains a RecyclerView within `inflater.inflate()`. You can re-use layout files; you don't need one layout file per activity or fragment (or with names related to their classes). The Activity layout will need a FrameLayout to load the Fragment. That's it. For example, I would just make a generic `layout/recyclerview.xml` file and `<include>` that into other XML files as needed.

Answer (score 1):

let's try to change

`recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));`

with

`recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));`

And make some update for onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity_fragment_two,container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.realm_recycler_view);
    setupRecyclerView();
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: @Reshad after you changes it move `recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.realm_recycler_view);
        setupRecyclerView();` to onCreateView

Comment: If you see my answer, your update still causes the error, apparently

Answer (score 0):

Inflate your recycler view on `onViewCreated()`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity_fragment_two,container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.realm_recycler_view);

setupRecyclerView();
return rootView;
}
```

Not in `onCreate`

Comment: Im assuming you removed setUpRecyclerView() from onCreate as well right?

Comment: yes, I have removed it there. I moved the recyclerview part of the content xml to the fragment xml and I seem to get the records now but it looks kinda weird ( screen sized rows ) :S

Comment: not following, is the NullPointerException still ocurring?

Comment: How does this differ from my answer?